# How to add a phtml file in cms page?

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to add a custome phtml file (that is placed in custome theme/template/brand/brand.phtml)  to a newly created cms page

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
{{block type="core/template" template="brand/brand.phtml"}}
```

Comment: In my experience for 1.9.2.3 you should also add the name="xxxx" attibute

Comment: My custom feedback module: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/32zqgejubfllz0h/AACkB_iIh-KJQxtEUikZ8i9Na?dl=0  how can i add into all pages including the home page.